# Unit testing, connection to api in UWP

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, uwp

Hi I have to write unit test to this method:

```
public static async Task<TradeModel[]> LoadTrades(int limit = 300)
{
    string url = "";

    if (limit <= 300)
    {
        url = $"https://api.bitbay.net/rest/trading/transactions/BTC-PLN?limit={ limit }";
    }
    else
    {

    }

    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiHelper.ApiClient.GetAsync(url))//exeption
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            TradeItemModel trade = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TradeItemModel>();

            return trade.Items;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
    }
}
```

And my unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 1, 26, 70, 5 };
    List<Type> expected = new List<Type> { typeof(TradeModel[]), typeof(TradeModel[]), typeof(TradeModel[]), typeof(TradeModel[]) };
    List<Type> actual = new List<Type>();

    for(int i= 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        var trades = await TradeProcessor.LoadTrades(numbers[i]);
        actual.Add(trades.GetType());
    }

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

I don't understand why I get an exeption Object reference not set to an instance of an object. What am I doing wrong? How this test should look like?

Comment: You should be mocking out `ApiHelper.ApiClient` so that you can control what `response` contains during your tests.  My guess is you aren't using dependency injection, which is why it's 'hard'.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without mocking? I don't have enough time to learn it now :/

Comment: If you are writing unit tests, you NEED mocking.   You need to make time to learn, it will save you lots of time in the long run.

Comment: Problem solved I have to use my ApiInitialize method

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error when implementing a unit test for WPF. In WPF you have to run the control in an Apartment Thread. To do this, I've used NUnit and tagged every unit test class with `[Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]`. Other Unit Test Frameworks should have similar ways of enforcing this Threading state...

```
    [Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]
    public class ByteTests
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestValues()
        {
        }
}
```